# Turn off browser audio in any browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

There is any way to turn off the browser audio for my web page. I had tried many  times but i can' t find a solution.

Comment: please add some code from your page.

Comment: If you don't have any audio playing, browser will not play on its own ;)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that what you want, cannot be done. No browser would allow a page to change the sound settings for the computer without user interaction. This would be a major security leak.

If you have something other in mind, clarify it in your question.

Hope I helped!

Answer (score -1):

**yes,** you can set your browser audio as well as set Mute it, do this way,

1. Right Click on Sound tray icon
2. Click "Open Volume Mixer"

[image]

3. Set your installed browser volume.

[image]